# HTTP 500 error in Aheadworks Blog Module in magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento-1.9, database, third-party-module, magento1.9.3

I am using aheadworks blog extension for magento community edition version 1.9.3.6. module is installed correctly and blog is showing at frontend. however when i click on blog's link. it shows HTTP 500 error.[image]

anyone has an idea, what is the reason behind this error?

Comment: try turning on show errors from your index.php file , to first know if there is any syntax error for the page

Comment: Have you checked **`exception.log`** under **`[documentroot]/var/log`** folder?

Answer (score 0):

There can be various reasons behind **`HTTP 500 error`**.

To find a clue, look in the Magento bootstrap file (index.php) you’ll see lines similar to the following

```
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
```

Uncomment these. This way, you will see the actual problem which leads to the Internal Error Server. In most cases, the reason is that there is an exception throw after the output is sent to the browser.

**Case 1:** This error might be caused because you have not set the correct permissions for the Magento folders. If you can fix the permissions on your own, it's good. Otherwise, you can try this [free tool](https://tzamtzis.gr/tzamtziswp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-cleanup.zip)

1. Download it
2. Unzip magento-check.php to the root directory of your Magento
   installation
3. Browse to http://yourdomain.com/magento-check.php

**Case 2:** If it is not your case, you may find that problem is due to insufficient memory resources on the server.

To fix this, increase the value of **`memory_limit`** from php.ini or Apache/Nginx configuration file.

**Case 3:** Try to remove .htaccess file in the document root for testing purpose.

If your website was running with this file for a long time, then it must be a change at Server side, just submit a ticket to Hosting Company.

**Case 4:** If the curl extension is missing you can get 500 Internal server error. Installing curl extension could solve the issue.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I checked this extension at localhost and found that error was coming from Head block because two extension was conflicting each other.